# cvNamedWindow destroys any previous windows

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to create two named windows, one to show the original video and other to show the processed video, however, the creation of the second named window destroys the first one. The documentation doesn't include much about named windows any I couldn't find anything relevant on google.

Here is my code:

```
cvNamedWindow( "Source", 1);
cvMoveWindow("Source", 0, 200);

// If I comment out the following lines, the original window continues on screen
cvNamedWindow( "Wire", 1);
cvMoveWindow("Wire", 600, 200);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be seeing it because it has no content. Try adding content to the window. This code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cv::Mat image, image2;
    image = cv::imread("pic1.jpg");
    image2 = cv::imread("pic2.jpg");

    if (!image.data || !image2.data) {
        std::cout << "Image file not found\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Source");
    cv::moveWindow("Source", 0, 200);
    cv::namedWindow("Wire");
    cv::moveWindow("Wire", 400, 200);

    cv::imshow("Source", image);
    cv::imshow("Wire", image2);
    // wait for key
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

produces this:

[image: two windows with content]

Comment: Actually, if the second window does not have content, both windows display normally. If I add content to the last window, the first disappears.

Comment: Ok, this was just stupidity of my part. One of the windows was been hidden by my window manager when the second window was created.